# How to add loader to website while Axios is getting data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting my data at very slow rate so when i open my website first time it takes some times untile showing all the product. So i want to add a loader untile my data is fully loaded.

i used custom  Hook to load data

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this, that I like, and is very straight forward is by adding conditional statements, meaning that if the data passed as a prop is currently **undefined** `return <div>Loading.....</div>` in opposite case return the JSX containing the prop data.

If you don't do this, React will show an error. This is because when fetching there is a time that the data is undefined and if React tries to do something with it before hand, it finds nothing. This conditions are a way to tell React when is a good time to access the data.

```
export default function MyComponent({someData}){

  if(!someData) return <div>Loading.....</div>
  else{
     return <div>{someData}</div>
  }
}
```